# What if there where no nodes to share a new block

Tags: blockchain, nodes, offline

I am fairly new to blockchain technology, so bear with me if i make mistakes

So lets say there are 10 people trading a cryptocurrency 5 of them are online from 8 to 10 am and the other half on online from 1 to 5 pm, if a person from the first group wants to make a transaction and adds that trasaction to the blockchain, it then gets send around among the 4 other people in the first ground that all add that block to their own blockchain, but then everyone of them goes offline and when the second group gets online there are no people from the first group to share that new block, so eventually the two blockchains would look completely different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes networks that are cut off from one another, cannot intercommunicate and therefore cannot transact with one another.

Comment: so blockchains break down for smaller networks?

Comment: Strictly speaking, networks that are too small to sustain communications among their members become unusable for any networked application.

Comment: The problem is also trivially solved by one or more nodes remaining online around the clock.